# Adding a multiply reducer to the Simplest Redux Example

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Given [one of react-redux's official hello world example](https://github.com/jackielii/simplest-redux-example/blob/master/index.js), how do I implement a `multiply` reducer? They implement a reducer that adds two numbers, however it'd also be beneficial to see a reducer with an input as the multiplier. I know this is very basic, but it's my broken down version of another project.

Here's my attempt at making this work:

```
const MULTIPLY_ACTION = 'MULTIPLY_ACTION'
   function multiplyAction(integer) {
     return {
       type: MULTIPLY_ACTION,
       integer
     }
   }

export function multiplier(state = { integer: 0 }, action) {
  switch () {
    case MULTIPLY_ACTION:
      console.log('multiplying', action)
      return {
        multiple: state.integer * action.multiplier
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

**Problems I am running into:**

1. Refactoring and making mapStateToProps() work with multiple reducers. What am I missing? [see refactor below]
2. Refactoring the `increaseAction` object literal into a function (action type?). In the original example, the moment I refactor `const increaseAction = { type: 'increase' }` into `const increaseAction = () => {type: 'increase'}`, the counter reducer doesn't get called anymore and my app fails silently (I'm using [create-react-app](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/07/22/create-apps-with-no-configuration.html) as a build).

[refactor].

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { increaseAction, multiplyAction } = state

  return {
    increaseAction,
    multiplyAction
  }
}
```

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your action gets dispatched to your reducer as an object, so you need to work with the object shape you define. For example you define your action to have a type: MULTIPLY_ACTION, as well as (by using property shorthand syntax) a property called integer, set to the value of the integer parameter.

Therefore your reducer needs to switch based on the type (you have an empty expression in your switch statement now, instead of say `action.type`), and then it needs to use the `action.integer`.

Then, your reducer represents a piece of your total application state object. Right now you define the default shape of that piece of state as being an object with a property called `integer` with a value of 0. You would want your action `case` statement to return the same shape as the default state object, so it should return an object with a single property called `integer`. In other words, your reducer should always return the same object shape (even if the properties are different, or possibly null if that is a valid value for your application. Just not undefined.)

So your reducer might have a case that says:

```
return { integer: state.integer * action.integer }
```

As far as your connect function, mapStateToProps is only aware of your state (not your actions), so it simply needs to return the part of state that you want. It is the second parameter, mapDispatchToProps, that is concerned with your actions. So you'd want something like:

```
connect(
  state => ({
    multiplierInteger: state.multiplier.integer // remember that you are looking within your reducer multiplier which contains an object that has the field you want, integer
  }),
  dispatch => ({
    multiplyAction(val) {
      dispatch(multiplyAction(val))
    }
  })
)
```

edit: It may be that I misunderstood your 'refactor', and now see that you were asking about using mapStateToProps to access multiple reducers. Well I still think my example may help, because you were trying to access the result of the reducers by the name of their related actions. What you want is instead to use the name of the reducer itself, which, assuming you are using combineReducers, is how Redux maps many reducers to a single state object.